# Hanging thread in SOAPUI Tests in Java app

Tags: java, soapui

I am trying to execute my SOAPUI test suites through a Java app rather than on the UI. However, when creating a WSDLProject a thread is starting that never gets killed, so when my code is executed and all the tests are run, the app doesnt end as this thread is still sitting there.

It looks like an AWT Daemon Thread

In the Eclipse Debugger:

```
Daemon Thread [AWT-Windows] (Running)
```

Here is my code:

```
WsdlProject projectName = String.format(
    "src/main/resources/%s-soapui-project.xml", projectName);
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject(projectName); //This line starts the thread

List<TestSuite> testSuites = project.getTestSuiteList();

//Loop over each testsuite
    //Loop over each test case
```

Does anyone know how to kill this thread?

Ive searched and searched the SOAPUI API, but the documentation is terrible and I cant find any decent examples of how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this with the following solution. It is not ideal but I could not find a way round this and the SOAP UI documentation is incredibly painful.

Firstly, I save the results of each test step to an xml file.

Next, once the tests have run I exit:

```
System.exit(runner.getOverallResult() ? 0 : 1);
```

Finally, another app executes this through a command line .sh script. After executing it the other app reads the XML file to determine the results.

Answer (score 5):

For the past two days I have been struggling with the same problem.  I have a solution which may help.  The reason your does not end is not the AWT-Windows thread.  The culprit is the thread labeled "Thread-2" which is of type **SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.IdleConnectionMonitorThread**

Unfortunately this thread which is created when you instantiate **WsdlProject**, has no directly accessible shutdown method.  This is what I had to do in-order to shut it down and have the JVM exit when my main routine exits:

Have your main method or some other method execute the following at the end:

```
// Need to shutdown all the threads invoked by each SoapUI TestSuite
SoapUI.getThreadPool().shutdown();
try {
        SoapUI.getThreadPool().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

// Now to shutdown the monitor thread setup by SoapUI
Thread[] tarray = new Thread[Thread.activeCount()];
Thread.enumerate(tarray);
for (Thread t : tarray) {
        if (t instanceof SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.IdleConnectionMonitorThread) {
                ((SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.IdleConnectionMonitorThread) t)
                .shutdown();
        }
}

// Finally Shutdown SoapUI itself.
SoapUI.shutdown();
```

Although ugly, I hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Do we have a official solution from SoapUI. because this is still occurring in their latest api. They have this shutdown method http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/support/http/SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.html  but I do not know where to get its context from :(

Comment: Works Great.! Thanks.